# NoSuchHostedZone error while creating an A record

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, boto3

When I run this boto3 to create an A record, I get the error:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (NoSuchHostedZone)
>   when calling the ChangeResourceRecordSets operation: No hosted zone
>   found with ID: my_zone

I am running boto3 and I know I create the hosted zone called "my_zone" and I can see it in the AWS console.

```
response2 = client.change_resource_record_sets(
HostedZoneId = 'my_zone',
ChangeBatch={
    'Comment': 'Points to an instance',
    'Changes': [
        {
            'Action': 'CREATE',
            'ResourceRecordSet': {
                'Name': 'fookeeper.bla',
                'Type': 'A',
                'SetIdentifier': 'my_a_record',
                'GeoLocation': {},  #  US is the default zone.
                'TTL': 300,
                'ResourceRecords': [
                    {
                        'Value': '172.31.11.50'
                    },
                    ],
                }
        },
        ]
}
```

)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hosted zone id is not the name of the hosted zone, but rather the Amazon assigned id of that zone.

If you open Route53 in the AWS console and select your hosted zone you will see "Hosted Zone Details" at the right.  The hosted zone id you need to use will be in that information pane labeled "Hosted Zone ID".  The id will be a random string of alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Thank you, I should have read the variable name more carefully, it does say HostedZoneId.  This is a generated value something like X2JUKEEOB9K4RZ

Comment: No worries.  Glad to help.